# Register Eureka Client as hostname instead of localhost

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have my Eureka server running on a remote raspberry pi. I have other Eureka clients on other pi's and they are working fine. I'm trying to run another client on my laptop but when it registers with the Eureka service it is registering as localhost. Obviously this will not work because the client is not running on the same host as the Eureka server. How can I get my client to register it self with the actual hostname (or IP) instead of localhost?

Answer (score 3):

You can either set `eureka.instance.hostname="your-host-name"` for the client in its config to whatever you want it to register with, or try setting `eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true`

See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html#spring-cloud-eureka-server-prefer-ip-address